# Ajax запрос в php и возвратом данных обратно

Tags: javascript, php

Заново переписал вопрос:

Генерируется страничка чата на php, в ней выведенно определённое количество сообщений, необходимо запомнить сколько сообщений было в БД на момент её генерации на сервере, у этой страницы есть файл js, необходимо каждую секунду, выполнять ajax запрос на сервер и проверять нынешнее количество сообщений в БД, соответственно, если оно будет отличатся, от того количества, которое было при генерации страницы, то мы обновляем страницу. Чтобы вывести новые сообщения.

Я прошу, помочь написать ajax запрос правильный на js(Jquery). А также как при генерации страницы передать значение переменной php, переменной в js.

Файл main.js:

```js
        var fn=function(){ 
            // Неправильный ajax запрос
            let id_product = 321;
            let qty_product = 2;

            $.ajax({ 
                url: "check.php", 
                // dataType: "json", // Для использования JSON формата получаемых данных
                method: "GET", // Что бы воспользоваться POST методом, меняем данную строку на POST   
                data: {"id_product": id_product,"qty_product": qty_product},
                
                    success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data); // Возвращаемые данные выводим в консоль
                } 
            });
            
            if (nowmess > prevmess){
                window.location.reload(); // Обновляем страницу
            }

            setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000);
        }
          
        setTimeout( fn,1000 );
```

Готовый код check.php:

```html
<?php 
require 'db.php';  // Подключаем файл управление базой данных

$colh = R::count('messages'); // Достаем количество сообщений в 

echo $colh;  // Отправляем обратно

?>
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke изучать когда и где выполняются PHP и JS

Comment: Это мой первый бэк на php, и он готов на 88%, да знаю очень много костылей, но это конкурсный проект в старшей школе. Почему нет?

Comment: Я написал, как раз чтобы мне скинули нормальный пример АЯКС запроса, плис

Comment: По поводу где php и js, дело в том, что я сильно затупил признаю, и не подумал на перёд, как уведомлять отдельных пользователей когда приходит сообщение, и именно поэтому сейчас занимаюсь, таким костылем, а return поскольку я хотел показать, что именно надо сделать, поскольку понимания ajax ноль

Comment: А не надо писать "чтобы скинули". Потому что их и так уже миллион накидали. Надо только очки купить

Comment: Тем не менее на решение натолкнул Ваш комментарий про return. Так что вопрос был задан не зря, благодарю

Comment: Вот кстати подскажите, муторно ли будет, и куда копать, чтобы вместо обновления страницы включая все файлы, просто обновить содержание сообщений?

Comment: туда же копать. запрашивать сами сообщения и отображать их

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот, разобрался. Готовый код js, привязанного к странице файла:

```js
var fn=function(){ 
            var nowmess;

            $.ajax({ 
                url: "check.php", 
                // dataType: "json", // Для использования JSON формата получаемых данных
                method: "GET", // Что бы воспользоваться POST методом, меняем данную строку на POST   
                data: {"nowmess": nowmess},
                
                success: function(data) {
                    nowmess = data;
                    if (nowmess > prevmess){
                        window.location.reload(); // Обновляем страницу
                    }
                } 
            });
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        }
          
        setTimeout(fn, 1000);
```

И на самой странице сохранил переменную из php в js:

```html
<script>
  var prevmess = <?php echo json_encode($colm); ?>; 
</script>
```